# XAMPP and Node.js on local windows 7 development machine

Tags: apache, node.js, xampp

I've being reading alot on how node.js can be used to add real time features to web applications. Am a PHP developer but i have good grasp on javascript.
I have XAMPP installed my windows 7 machine which i use for development and i just installed node.js using the windows installer on the node.js site.
How do i make app communicate with the node.js server ?

Comment: What app? What kind of communication? You should express the question in an another way, it's too broad

Comment: @Mustafa i'd like to user node.js to push notifications to the app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm on OSX, and I'm basically heading down this same path.

First off, don't think of node.js like you would PHP and think you're setting up a vhost in XAMPP.

You need to look in to getting node.js to be listening as a server. There are several tutorials out there that go over this, but this one can help get you started:

http://www.albatrossrevue.com/2012/01/31/an-introduction-to-node-js/2000

Comment: Any chance of an update on this? The link is also broken for me :(

Comment: Try it with these (for `Windows`): http://askhds.blogspot.com/2012/01/nodejs-get-starting-with-nodejs-on_24.html or coming from this comment http://stackoverflow.com/a/15331497/1696030 http://dailyjs.com/2012/05/03/windows-and-node-1/