# How can I use Nodejs with Windows 7?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, webserver, websocket

I'm about to became insane looking for it, most of the examples shows only how to run it on linux terminal and just the communication with the server.
Can someone PLEASE explain to me how I can use NodeJs (make it run and load whatever is needed) in Windows 7?

and PLEASE, how can I integrate it with my HTML5 code?

I really appreciate your answers

Comment: http://nodejs.org/download/ Windows download link is _right there._

Comment: An excellent resource http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js

Comment: as you see  same post is already exists

Comment: remember once you have installed node js you will probably need to restart your computer.After that node js is available from the command prompt.

Comment: I wouldnt have posted that if I have found it b4, and whats the point in being blocked, we can always create new accounts...

Comment: ow, and thanks for the answer aura, rly helpfull

Comment: @AkshatJiwanSharma Thanks for the tip! I had to restart my PC after installing `node.js` to be able to use it from the command prompt. I created an issue on the project's GitHub page to change the MSI  to force a restart at the end of installation. https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5591

Comment: Actually I don't think you have to restart your computer to get Windows working with Node.js. You actually just need to close your dos/command window and reopen a new one to refresh the environment variables that node needs to find itself in the path.. (I just installed it and that worked for me).

Comment: Don't use caps, and no need for such words like `please`. Just post your problem in a comprehensible way. Everyone with a programming problem is welcome in this community and we are all willing to help.

Comment: I don't blame OP. This was my first search result on Google. This awkward situation could have been avoided if there was actually a Getting Started section on the NodeJS website, but nooo.

Comment: the worked version for win 7 is : https://nodejs.org/download/release/v13.6.0/ and this article helps me a lot: https://www.centennialsoftwaresolutions.com/post/install-node-js-on-windows-7

Answer (score 41):

From:
[http://dailyjs.com/2012/05/03/windows-and-node-1/](https://web.archive.org/web/20141012211148/http://dailyjs.com/2012/05/03/windows-and-node-1/)

To download Node, go to [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org), click [“Download”](https://nodejs.org/en/download/), and click “Windows Installer”. This will give you a Windows Installer (MSI) file that will install Node and npm.

The article contains a hello world tutorial.

Comment: Worth linking this maybe...  Released recently.  [Node.JS tools for Visual Studio](https://nodejstools.codeplex.com/)  Can't seem to install it on rhel though :)

Comment: Checkout this link

http://blueashes.com/2011/web-development/install-nodejs-on-windows/

Comment: The best example is here http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows